# In Azure DevOps is there a way to restrict a member of a Team to create Work Items only for specific Area Paths and Iterations?

Tags: azure-devops

We're looking to use a DevOps project per customer and within each customer run multiple projects.

To do this we can set up multiple Teams/Areas and have associated Iterations and choose the default Iterations for each Area, that's all good.

However if you choose to create a new Work Item, you can still choose any Area and any Iteration.  Ideally we'd want to limit members of each specific Team/Area to only be able to choose the Area and Iterations for their project.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue , you can set the permission in the `Team configuration` of project settings.

Team configuration -> Areas -> the specific area -> Security -> Deny `Edit work items in this node` permission

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hugh Lin, the challenge seems to be if you're a member of more than 1 group (Team)  with different permissions, then the deny will override the allow (understandable).  Looks like we may have to do the permissions individually rather than at a Group level. Unless you know a workaround to this?

Comment: If it is such a special member, I think we can only set the permission for these special members individually.